# How can I allow users to create their own posts in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to build a discussion forum with Django. I first did a test post with Django admin, but now wanted to implement a form so that any user can post. The idea is that the home page of the forum has a list of all existing posts, and clicking on the "Create a Post" button would take them to the post form, and after submitting they can see their post on the list. I have the code for the form ready and thought I had hooked it up correctly to the URL, but I am getting a blank page when I click on "Create a Post". I am new to Django, and need some help solving this. Here are my files:

Models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60, default= 'None')
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Your Name"
        })
    )
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Leave a comment!"
        })
    )

class PostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Title"
        })
    )    
    author = forms.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Your Name"
        })
    )
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Leave a Post!"
        })
    )
```

Views.py:

```
def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    context = {
        "posts": posts,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)

def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__name__contains=category
    ).order_by(
        '-created_on'
    )
    context = {
        "category": category,
        "posts": posts
    }
    return render(request, "blog_category.html", context)

def blog_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)

    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "comments": comments,
        "form":form,
    }

    return render(request, "blog_detail.html", context)

def blog_post(request):

    post_form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = Post(
                title=post_form.cleaned_data["title"],
                author=post_form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=post_form.cleaned_data["body"],
            )
            post.save()

    context = {
        "post_form":post_form,
    }

    args= {}
    args['post_form']= post_form

    return render(request, "blog_post.html", args)
```

And here are the URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
    path("post_form/", views.blog_post, name="blog_post")
]
```

Lastly, here are the htmls for the post index and the post form (I also have two other html files for the post detail and the post category, but I think those are not necessary for me to post now).

forum index html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>Blog Index</h1>
    <hr>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <h2><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' post.pk%}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <small>
        {{ post.created_on.date }} |&nbsp;
        Categories:&nbsp;
        {% for category in post.categories.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>&nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    </small>
    <p>{{ post.body | slice:":400" }}...</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog_post' %}" role="button">Create a Post</a>
    

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Post form html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
<h3>Write your post:</h3> 
    <form action="/blog/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ post_form.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ post_form.author }}
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ post_form.body }}
        </div> 
        <a button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog_index' %}" role="button">Submit</a>
        
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Please be so kind to narrow your question down. Additionally, remove the `php` tag as it does not seem to belong to `python` and `django`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
    path("blog_detail/<int:pk>", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("blog_category/<str:category>", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
    path("blog_post/", views.blog_post, name="blog_post")
]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly to show the post form! But, now when I submit the post it is not showing on the index page. In other words, it is like the index is not being updated with the new posts. Any ideas why the new posts are not being pulled? I suspect this might be something either on the forms or the html file.

Comment: Few issues I found here, first of all, did you properly imported the modules? for example ```from .models import Post, Comment, Category``` and ```from .forms import PostForms, and other forms``` If imported properly you need to specify the app name to route while rendering for example ```return render(request, "APPNAME/blog_post.html", args)``` 
if you think the solution in the answer section worked please "accept" as an answer so that if someone visits this for the same problem he could understand this is the solution like how this sites work and kindly upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just upvoted your solution. I did check that all models are imported properly. If by chance you are able to see why the post index is not being updated please do advise. I have checked everything but can't seem to solve this step.

Comment: Please do check if you have rendered with the app name or not as mentioned ```return render(request, "APPNAME/blog_post.html", args) ``` If you are not sure upload this project into Github and share the GitHub link. You can edit the question and add a GitHub link there. Once you provide me the GitHub link I'll be able to provide a complete solution to your problem that will work as desired.